# How to address people who are interested in my course?

Tags: word-choice

I have prepared a document with information for those who are interested in the course that I teach (science) for diploma.

My question is how should I address them when I open this document?

Does "**Dear applicant**" work (in formal writing) or I should use different words?

Comment: Not just for formality's sake, no.  Do you want to make it clear that the intended audience of your document (the people you're writing for) is people interested in the course?

Comment: Yes. How should I do that?

Comment: Are you teaching a course i.e. giving a course? Because it sounds like you are taking a course. One does not apply for courses. One takes a course. And once you are in a university, you sign up for one. So, the logical thing here would be: Dear Student

Comment: Indeed I'm a student,  but It's 'based on a real story' of my relative. But for the purpose of the question,  I didn't think it's something important to note.

Comment: I didn't ask if you were a student. You are not answering my question. Usually, people who try and get into courses that are not open for everyone are still students.

Answer (score 1):

Applicant is not the correct word as I believe they have not applied for the course as of the time of your writing.

"Dear enquirer" would work. It's simple and straight forward.

If you want a little bit more fluff and fun I'd suggest "Dear aspirant", just not in Russia where it may be misinterpreted (Aspirant being a PhD equivalent level degree).

Comment: Dear Enquirer? Sorry, but I have never heard that.

Comment: Never heard of enquirer? That's odd. If the whole then Dear... can work with just about any proper noun. There are many combinations I haven't heard of but that doesn't make them invalid.

Comment: Certainly not used to address students.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving a science course.

The students are already enrolled in the university/school.

The best term here is:

Dear Student

One doesn't apply for a course; one applies for a job.

If courses are by special admittance only (students who have shown they have a high level), it would still be Dear Student.

Comment: It was one academical course only… as a preperation for a univeraity. Not anyone was admitted,  that's why I thought to use applicant.

Comment: The OP never makes it certain that the interested parties have enrolled yet. If there is some that haven't then student is too restrictive a term.

Comment: @JudiciousAllure academical course?? academic course. They would still be students. Potential or actual students. Even if they are not accepted into the course, they took some sort of exam or test to gain admittance to the course. Dear Student.

Comment: @PaulChilds If there is some? If there are some [students]

Answer (score 1):

"Applicant" would not sound unnatural to most native-english speakers, however it does not seem appropriate for this situation, and could be confusing for a non-native speaker. For something like this I would use "Dear Prospective Student". This gives a small amount of ambiguity, and leaves room for information seekers up until student status.

"Applicant" would imply that the letter is addressed to someone who has applied previously, but has not been admitted.

"Student" would be appropriate for someone who has already applied and been accepted.